# Display images using masonry

Tags: javascript, masonry

I'm new for web developing. I want to display images in grid layout. my images have same width but different height.
To display images without gap between them i used masonry plugin. But it doesn't work for me. Can anyone help me find out the error please..

This is my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>FlashTemplatesDesign </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.tools.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<script>
var container = document.querySelector('#test');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  // options
  columnWidth: 200,
  itemSelector: '.imagedisplay'
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="test">

<?php 
 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
 mysql_select_db("selfie") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

 //Retrieves data from MySQL 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image_upload INNER JOIN user_table
ON image_upload.user_id=user_table.user_id  ORDER BY timestamp DESC; ") or           die(mysql_error());


    //Puts it into an array

 while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
 //Outputs the image and other data 
 Echo

 '<div class="imagedisplay">' .'<img src="uploads/'.$info['image'].'" width="230px"     height=auto border="1px solid #"
-webkit-border-radius=" 20px"
-moz-border-radius= "20px"
border-radius="20px"  
   >'. '</div>';

   }

 ?>  
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right off hand it looks like you're trying to reference the images and container in your JavaScript before the document is loaded. Try moving your script tag with code after (or right before) the closing `</body>` tag.

Because the document hasn't fully loaded, the DOM API in JavaScript can't yet access those elements if your JavaScript is in the head.

Comment: Do you still see the images, even though the masonry hasn't been applied yet?

Comment: Yes i can still see the images with gaps

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to wait for the images to load before you organize the elements with masonry.

[From masonry appendix:](http://masonry.desandro.com/appendix.html)

```
// initialize Masonry after all images have loaded
imagesLoaded( container, function() {
  msnry = new Masonry( container );
});
```